# Explain the following output for C program

Tags: c, global-variables

I wrote this C program with the following output

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int counter; // global for counting input tokens
char * CreateTemp()
{ 
 int counter; // for counting temporaries
 char s[10];
 sprintf(s,"T%d",counter++);
 return(strdup(s));
}
main()
{
 char *s1;
 char *s2;
 char *s3;
 s1=CreateTemp();
 s2=CreateTemp();
 printf("Temp is %s\n",s1);
 printf("Temp is %s\n",s2);
 s3=CreateTemp();
 printf("Temp is %s\n",s3);
}
```

Output:

```
Temp is T0  //Temp is T0
Temp is T1  //Temp is T1
Temp is T32600 //Temp is T2
```

I don't know why I got the output like this for T2? What is the reason?

When I removed:

int counter; // for counting temporaries

...I got:

```
Temp is T0 
Temp is T1 
Temp is T2
```

Why, when I removed the specific line:

```
Int counter; / for counting temporaries
```

Did I get the correct result, but when I kept it I got confusing results for `T2`?

Also, why when I add `static` to:

```
int counter; // for counting temporaries
```

To become:

```
static int counter; // for counting temporaries
```

And remove:

```
int counter; // global for counting input tokens
```

did I also got the correct result?

Comment: You're reading a local variable (`counter` as declared in `CreateTemp`) before assigning any value to it. This leads to undefined behaviour. Anything (including the program crashing any time you call `CreateTemp`) could have happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 int counter; // for counting temporaries
 char s[10];
 sprintf(s,"T%d",counter++);
```

- You have to initialize variables in C. Othewise their value
  is undefined; often something random.
- If you want the local variable to keep the same between calls to the function, you can make it `static`:

  ```
  static int counter = 0;
  ```

It's also a bad idea to have both a local and global variable with the same name. When you delete your line you end up using the global variable. That's why it works then.

Answer (score 6):

Local variables aren't initialized by default and using them without assigning them an explicit value yields **undefined behavior**, which means **anything may happen**.

The C standard literally doesn't define what happens, so it's a (un)lucky coincidence your first two strings are correct while the last one isn't. From the C standard's point of view, undefined behavior can even cause your machine to explode.

Global variables are initialized to zero by default.

Answer (score 5):

The int counter inside CreateTemp is "hiding" the global counter definition, so that is always 0, and since the counter inside CreateTemp is not initialized, you're getting whatever data happens to be there.